# Square Root Confusion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

well we know that $$\sqrt{x^2} = \pm x$$ 
Then if $$x^2=y^2$$
then $$\pm x= \pm y$$
Does this mean $x = y$ or $-x = -y$ or $x = -y$ or $-x = y$ or all is true? Which is true among these?

Comment: I guess I'm not part of *we* because I don't know $\sqrt{x^2} = \pm x$.  I thought $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ -- that is, by convention only the *nonnegative* value is assigned to the square root function.  In fact that's why $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is sometimes called the *principal square root function*.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}$ is NOT $\pm x$. We have $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Comment: You know that at least one of them is true, but you're not sure which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $x = y$ if and only if $-x = -y$.
Also, $x = -y$ if and only if $-x = y$.
So there are really only two possibilities:

$$x = y  \qquad \mbox{or} \qquad x = -y.$$

In other words, once you know that $x^2 = y^2$,
then you know that $x$ and $y$ have the same magnitude
(the same absolute value);
you also know that either $x$ and $y$ are exactly the same number
(same magnitude and same sign),
or they are exactly opposite (same magnitude but opposite signs;
one is positive and the other is negative).

Answer (score 0):

If $x^2=y^2$, then $y=\pm x$, which is the same as $x=\pm y$.  But $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt {x^2}= \sqrt {y^2} \implies |x|=|y| \implies \pm y=\pm x$$ 
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/debdx80itq

Comment: Yea, a total of 4 combinations: y=+-x and x=+-y, but they are redundant as y= +- x implies +-y=x (if you divide both sides by a negative, positive 1.)